# Knowing the longitude and latitude of a lunar crater, can I calculate how close to the centre of the disk it will appear to be?

Tags: geometry

I am seeking a formula to enable me to take the latitude and longitude of a lunar crater (lots of them actually) and turn that into a percentage figure of the distance from the centre of the disc to the edge.

Criteria:

- Assume the moon is a perfect sphere
- The "origin" is always at the exact centre of the disc (ignore any libration)

As an example, the crater Copernicus, located at 20W and 10N is about 38% of the way from the centre of the disc to the edge [I have measured this one on a map, but it would be overly tedious to plot/measure all of them individually].

I have looked at spherical triangles, and although this gives me an "on the ground" distance, I can't see how to convert this to the "apparent" distance from the centre when viewed on the 2D face of the moon.  The apparent "bunching" of the lines of latitude and longitude as you approach the edge is causing the problem.

My ideal solution would be a formula I can plug into a "calculated" field on my crater database and get the computer to do all the number crunching for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If we further assume that

- the meridian with longitude $0$ is seen as projected on the vertical $z$ axis,
- our distance from the moon is big with respect with the moon radius

then a point $(x,y,z)$ on the surface is seen as projected on the point $(0,y,z)$, if our point of view is far away on the $x$ axis.

If we use spherical coordinates:

$$
x = R\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
y = R\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
z = R\cos\theta
$$

then the distance of this point from the center is:

$$
d=\sqrt{y^2+z^2}=R\sqrt{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi}
$$

and if the apparent size of the radius of the moon is $r$, then the distance should be

$$
d=\sqrt{y^2+z^2}=r\sqrt{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi}
$$

Take into account that $\theta$ is not the latitude, but the latitude is $\pi/2-\theta$.